# Cycling though variables

Tags: c++, algorithm, loops, c++11, ref

I have got this code working so far but right now it's only storing the last variable when cycles through in the multi-dimensional array.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    const int columns = 5, rows = 5;
    int menuSelection;
    string word1 = "sloan", word2 = "horse", word3 = "eqrit", word4 = "house", word5 = "water";
    string table[rows][columns];

    for (auto &var : { ref(word1), ref(word2), ref(word3), ref(word4), ref(word5) })
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) 
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j) 
            {
                string test = var;
                table[i][j] = test[i];
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < columns; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < rows; ++j)
        {
            std::cout << table[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
w w w w w 
a a a a a 
t t t t t 
e e e e e 
r r r r r
```

I would like it do display different words on each row of the array's output:

```
s l o a n
h o r s e 
e g r i t    
h o u s e    
w a t e r
```

Comment: @RemyLebeau updated with desired output.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? Why `table[rows][cols] = {"sloan", "horse", "eqrit", "house", "water"}` doesn't suit you?

Comment: @n.m. Im separating the strings into individual chars to populate the multidimensional array

Comment: Evidently you are doing something else, but the question is not what you are doing, the question is why you are doing that. What result do you want to achieve in the end?

Comment: Im trying to do that of which is in my initial post for the output to correctly populate and display.

Comment: If you want that output, why not start with a cotrectly initialised array of characters and omit three nested loops, std::string, references, and all the errors that accompany these unneeded things?

Answer (score 2):

If you only care about having a desired output, all you do is a lot of unnecessary code. Of course for learning something, you could go with different longer ways to achieve the result.

However, if you care about a simple solution, you need simply an `std::array` of `std::string`s and iterate through them to print.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <string>

int main() 
{
    const std::array<std::string, 5> words { "sloan", "horse", "eqrit", "house", "water" };

    for (const auto& word: words)
    {
        for (const char charactor: word)  std::cout << charactor << " ";
        std::cout << '\n';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your code will loop the list of the string and set each character at each space like this

loop 1

```
s s s s s
l l l l l
o o o o o
a a a a a
n n n n n
```

loop 2

```
h h h h h
o o o o o
r r r r r
s s s s s
e e e e e
```

loop 3...

And so on

try this code instead

```
const int columns = 5, rows = 5;

string list[] = {"sloan", "hores", "eqrit", "house", "water"};
string table[rows][columns];

for(int i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
{
    string currentString = list[i];

    for(int j = 0; j < columns; ++j)
    {

        table[i][j] = currentString[j];
    }
}

for(int i = 0; i < columns; ++i)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < rows; ++j)
    {
        std::cout << table[i][j] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looping through each word, populating the entire array with individual chars from the first word, then overwriting the entire array with chars from the second word, then the third word, and so on.

So yes, in the end, the array ends up populated with only the chars of the last word.

You need to rethink your loops. You don't need 3 nested loops when 2 will suffice.

Try something more like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    const int columns = 5, rows = 5;

    string words[] = {
        "sloan",
        "horse",
        "eqrit",
        "house",
        "water"
    };

    string table[rows][columns];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        string &test = words[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j) {
            table[i][j] = test[j];
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; ++j) {
            std::cout << table[i][j] << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output

```
s l o a n 
h o r s e 
e q r i t 
h o u s e 
w a t e r
```

[Live Demo](https://www.ideone.com/hYbber)